# Find the rule of a sequence

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, number-theory

I have a sequence $\{x(n), n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ as follows:

$x(0) = 1$

$x(1) = 1- e^{-a}$

$x(2) = \dfrac 12(1 - 4e^{-a} + 3e^{-2a})$

$x(3) = \dfrac{1}{6}(1-12e^{-a}+27e^{-2a}-16e^{-3a}) $

$x(4) = \dfrac{1}{24}(1-32e^{-a}+162e^{-2a} -256e^{-3a}+125e^{-4a})$

$\ldots$

where $a$ is a constant.

I try to find an explicit formula by $n$ for this sequence but I still have not done yet. Can anyone can give me an idea or solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the coefficient $25$ in $x(4)$ is correct?

Comment: Where does this come from? Any way to generate further elements? If not, any guess is good...

Comment: @ David: I'm sorry, I did a mistake. In $x(4)$, it is 256 instead of 25.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? - 
$$x(n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k(k+1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}e^{-ka}\ .$$

Comment: Yes, it's the formula that I need. Thank you very much Did.